# checking if the record is already in the database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the fastest way to check if the record is already in the database.
I don't have unique id.
It could be checked after values as name, surname, date of birth

Comment: It might be a simple query in some situations, but in a multiuser environment such a check will fail and you end with many duplicate entries. The simple answer is: it depends, there are too little details in the question to give a proper  answer, I vote to close the question as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the fastest way to check for the existence of a row is to use the SELECT-INTO (implicit cursor) statement, as opposed to the explicit cursor. It is consistently faster *when* a row is found. When a row is not found, SELECT-INTO raises NO_DATA_FOUND and exception handling is relatively slow.

So when you write your code, think about the context, think about the data and patterns of usage. Do you expect the query to usually find a row? Then go with SELECT-INTO. Do you think that usually the fetch will fail? Then go with the explicit cursor.

Of course as noted by @Randy you do need to make sure you have the correct indexes in place to ensure an optimized lookup.

My [blog post](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/12/implicit-vs-explicit-cursor-which.html) on this topic should help fill in details and give you some code against which to exercise these ideas. But I will also post here to make it easier.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tmr 
IS 
   PROCEDURE start_timer; 

   PROCEDURE show_elapsed (str IN VARCHAR2); 
END tmr; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tmr 
IS 
   last_timing   NUMBER := NULL; 

   PROCEDURE start_timer 
   IS 
   BEGIN 
      last_timing := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time; 
   END; 

   PROCEDURE show_elapsed (str IN VARCHAR2) 
   IS 
   BEGIN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 
            str 
         || ': ' 
         || MOD (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - last_timing + POWER (2, 32), 
                 POWER (2, 32))); 
      start_timer; 
   END; 
END tmr; 
/

CREATE TABLE not_much_stuff (n NUMBER)
;

INSERT INTO not_much_stuff
       SELECT LEVEL
         FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL < 11
;

-- Demonstration of Exception Behavior with SELECT-INTO
DECLARE 
   my_n   not_much_stuff.n%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No rows found:'); 

   BEGIN 
      SELECT n 
        INTO my_n 
        FROM not_much_stuff 
       WHERE n = -1; 
   EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
      THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack); 
   END; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Too many rows found:'); 

   BEGIN 
      SELECT n 
        INTO my_n 
        FROM not_much_stuff 
       WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 10; 
   EXCEPTION 
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS 
      THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack); 
   END; 
END;
/

DECLARE 
   my_n   not_much_stuff.n%TYPE; 
BEGIN    
   tmr.start_timer; 
   FOR indx IN 1 .. 10000 
   LOOP 
      BEGIN 
         SELECT n 
           INTO my_n 
           FROM not_much_stuff 
          WHERE n = -1; 

         my_n := 100; 
      EXCEPTION 
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
         THEN 
            my_n := 100; 
      END; 
   END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (my_n); 

   tmr.show_elapsed ('Implicit Failure'); 
END;

/

DECLARE 
   my_n   not_much_stuff.n%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
   tmr.start_timer; 

   FOR indx IN 1 .. 10000 
   LOOP 
      BEGIN 
         SELECT n 
           INTO my_n 
           FROM not_much_stuff 
          WHERE n = 1; 

         my_n := 100; 
      EXCEPTION 
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
         THEN 
            my_n := 100; 
      END; 
   END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (my_n); 

   tmr.show_elapsed ('Implicit Success'); 
END;
/

DECLARE 
   my_n   not_much_stuff.n%TYPE; 

   CURSOR stuff_cur 
   IS 
      SELECT n 
        FROM not_much_stuff 
       WHERE n = -1; 
BEGIN 
   tmr.start_timer; 

   FOR indx IN 1 .. 10000 
   LOOP 
      OPEN stuff_cur; 

      FETCH stuff_cur INTO my_n; 

      IF stuff_cur%NOTFOUND 
      THEN 
         my_n := 100; 
      END IF; 

      CLOSE stuff_cur; 
   END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (my_n); 

   tmr.show_elapsed ('Explicit Failure'); 
END;
/

DECLARE 
   my_n   not_much_stuff.n%TYPE; 

   CURSOR stuff_cur 
   IS 
      SELECT n 
        FROM not_much_stuff 
       WHERE n = 1; 
BEGIN 
   tmr.start_timer; 

   FOR indx IN 1 .. 10000 
   LOOP 
      OPEN stuff_cur; 

      FETCH stuff_cur INTO my_n; 

      IF stuff_cur%FOUND 
      THEN 
         my_n := 100; 
      END IF; 

      CLOSE stuff_cur; 
   END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (my_n); 

   tmr.show_elapsed ('Explicit Success'); 
END;
/

-- 1. Implicit cursor inside a nested block
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_stuff_with_employee (  
   employee_id_in   IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE)  
IS  
   l_name   hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;  
BEGIN  
   BEGIN  
      SELECT last_name  
        INTO l_name  
        FROM hr.employees e  
       WHERE e.employee_id = do_stuff_with_employee.employee_id_in;  
   EXCEPTION  
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND  
      THEN  
         /* log the error if this really is an error or let it go... */  
         l_name := NULL;  
   END;  

   IF l_name IS NOT NULL  
   THEN  
      /* continue with application logic */  
      NULL;  
   END IF;  
END; 
/

-- 2. Implicit cursor inside a nested subprogram
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_stuff_with_employee (  
   employee_id_in   IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE)  
IS  
   l_name   hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;  

   FUNCTION emp_name (employee_id_in IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE)  
      RETURN hr.employees.last_name%TYPE  
   IS  
      l_name   hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;  
   BEGIN  
      SELECT last_name  
        INTO l_name  
        FROM hr.employees  
       WHERE employee_id = employee_id_in;  

      RETURN l_name;  
   EXCEPTION  
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND  
      THEN  
         /* log the error if this really is an error or let it go... */  
         RETURN NULL;  
   END;  
BEGIN  
   l_name := emp_name (employee_id_in);  

   IF l_name IS NOT NULL  
   THEN  
      /* continue with application logic */  
      NULL;  
   END IF;  
END; 
/

-- 3. Explicit cursor unconcerned with too many rows
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_stuff_with_employee (  
   employee_id_in   IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE)  
IS  
   l_name   hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;  

   CURSOR name_cur  
   IS  
      SELECT last_name  
        FROM hr.employees e  
       WHERE e.employee_id = do_stuff_with_employee.employee_id_in;  
BEGIN  
   OPEN name_cur;  

   FETCH name_cur INTO l_name;  

   CLOSE name_cur;  

   IF l_name IS NOT NULL  
   THEN  
      /* continue with application logic */  
      NULL;  
   END IF;  
END; 
/

-- 4. Explicit cursor that checks for too many rows
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_stuff_with_employee (  
   employee_id_in   IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE)  
IS  
   l_name    hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;  
   l_name2   hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;  

   CURSOR name_cur  
   IS  
      SELECT last_name  
        FROM hr.employees e  
       WHERE e.employee_id = do_stuff_with_employee.employee_id_in;  
BEGIN  
   OPEN name_cur;  

   FETCH name_cur INTO l_name;  

   FETCH name_cur INTO l_name2;  

   IF name_cur%FOUND  
   THEN  
      CLOSE name_cur;  

      RAISE TOO_MANY_ROWS;  
   ELSE  
      CLOSE name_cur;  
   END IF;  

   IF l_name IS NOT NULL  
   THEN  
      /* continue with application logic */  
      NULL;  
   END IF;  
END; 
/
```

Comment: I was tooling around in SO and was so pleased to see a great answer...and then I saw it was SF. Figures...

Answer (score 0):

you can do these things:

1. query for it.  Add an index to help that query go faster

If eventually inserting:

2. Add a unique index - and insert the values - errors mean it is already there
3. Merge into it.

Comment: can u show me exemplary code?

Comment: no.  this depends on your tables and your intent.  i agree with comments above - too broad - voting to close

Answer (score 0):

And I must say what is very often used for checking if the record is already in the database, but is 
highly  NOT recommended! That is counting of all rows just to check:

```
    DECLARE
       count_var   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT (*)
         INTO count_var
         FROM not_much_stuff
        WHERE n = -1;

       IF count_var = 0
       THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No rows found!');
       ELSIF count_var > 1
       THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Too many rows found!');
       ELSE
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('One row exists!');
       END IF;
    END;
```

Please never use this! This is example of programming laziness!